# GitLab remote repository with a non standard port

Tags: git, ssh, nginx, gitlab

I have the following error:

```
ssh: connect to host git.limeworks.eu port 22: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Now, the configuration I have in my local .ssh/config file is:

```
host limeworks
    user git
    port 6565
    hostname git.limeworks.eu;
```

and in the remote gitlab.yml:

```
  gitlab:
    ## Web server settings
    host: git.limeworks.eu
    port: 6565
```

Also, here's the nginx setup (/sites-enabled/gitlab):

```
server {
  listen 80;         # e.g., listen 192.168.1.1:80; In most cases *:80 is a good idea
  server_name git.limeworks.eu;     # e.g., server_name source.example.com;
...
```

I have restarted the gitlab and nginx services after each modification, yet nothing works!

Edit: Also worth noting here are some snippets from sshd_config of the remote server

```
Port 9595
AllowUsers rrw git
```

Comment: Sorry for question, but: is you have two servers - one with installed GitLab and second with GIT repository. And GitLab work with remote GIT repository to retrieve code fro it. Is it correct?

Answer (score 4):

Ok , found the fix:

- in gitlab.yml ... under advanced setting there's an option to change the default ssh port

> ```
> # If you use non-standard ssh port you need to specify it
> ssh_port:9595
> ```

- save and restart service

Make sure to have the consistency @VonC mentioned

Comment: +1. You had to have the same port number in both config, as I had mentioned in my answer.

Comment: If this is the correct solution, why didn't you accept the answer from @VonC?

Answer (score 2):

You need to check that this work:

```
ssh -vvvT limeworks
```

A good debug option is to launch a debug session of your ssh daemon (`sshd -d`) and see what an ssh command from the client side triggers on the server side.

I suppose your `sshd_config` should list the right port on which you expect ssh to listen to: 6595 instead of 9595. Check the [doc on `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`](http://www.faqs.org/docs/securing/chap15sec122.html).

Comment: ok, i've updated the ssh_config(local) and gitlab.yml with the port from sshd_config... the ssh debug works fine(i think):`Transferred: sent 3200, received 2432 bytes, in 0.9 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 3574.4, received 2716.5
debug1: Exit status 0` but the connection is refused with the same port 22... i don't even have a clue where port 22 is stored

Comment: @RobinR.Winton you need to check at which port your ssh daemon is listening on the server side, and this is on your sshd config file. Again: type a `sshd -d` to see what is going on.