# Using a gitlab private repo as a golang dependancy in docker

Tags: docker, go, gitlab

I am mirroring a popular go library in my organizations gitlab's group (for redundancy).

In my code I have: `import ( "gitlab.com/org/group/library.git" )`

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27501172/8980988) for guidance on using go get with a private repository. On my machine `go get ./...` works because I configured git using the following command:

```
$ git config --global url.git@gitlab.com:.insteadOf https://gitlab.com/
```

When I try to build a docker container the command `RUN go get ./...` fails with the following output:

```
package gitlab.com/org/group/library.git: cannot download, git://gitlab.com/org/group/library uses insecure protocol
```

It seems the popular answer from a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26161541/docker-go-get-from-a-private-github-repo) or [this article](https://divan.github.io/posts/go_get_private/) is to do something like upload your ssh keys to the docker container. I don't really feel comfortable with that because I don't exactly understand what is doing, or the security implications.

Any insight on how to properly configure my dockerfile or my golang work flow would be of great assistance.

Comment: Read [an article](https://medium.com/@tonistiigi/build-secrets-and-ssh-forwarding-in-docker-18-09-ae8161d066) today about new improvements in docker that allows sharing secrets during docker build time. Does that help?

Comment: I am using this approach for my environment variables that I need to inject into my containers, this doesn't really apply to using a private repository as a pkg in my gland project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that golang v1.11 includes [modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules).

To quote the source

> A module is a collection of related Go packages that are versioned together as a single unit. Most often, a single version-control repository corresponds exactly to a single module.

Using the latest version of golang along with modules allows me to use all of my dependencies.