# How to install a go library from github without public key?

Tags: git, go

I want to install the [gqrcode project](https://github.com/KangSpace/gqrcode) and get from that project the following installation instructions:

```
go get -u github.com/KangSpace/gqrcode
```

When performing this, I first got:

```
...

fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled

...
```

After performing

```
git config --global --add url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```

I get:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
package github.com/KangSpace/gqrcode: exit status 1
```

In other languages like python I can clone the library first (`git clone ....`) and afterwards install it.

How can I perform something similar in go?

Comment: You can clone the repo to a folder, and use `replace` in `go.mod` to point to your local copy. See [How to use a module that is outside of "GOPATH" in another module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52328952/how-to-use-a-module-that-is-outside-of-gopath-in-another-module/52330233#52330233)

Comment: thanks, that was already really helpful. I changed into the directory of the repository and executed `go mod init gqrcode`. Afterwards I executed `go run qrcode.go` in that directory and get another error message: `build command-line-arguments: cannot load github.com/gqrcode/core/cons: git ls-remote -q https://github.com/gqrcode/core in /home/user/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/e2ffcd550d6d1ab2e65ad40d2c1d453aef1bce46b839e0ad91b20ba86131449e: exit status 128:
 fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
Confirm the import path was entered correctly.`

Comment: Do this (manual `git clone` and `replace`) with all private repos the `go` tool cannot handle. `github.com/KangSpace/gqrcode` is a public repo and `go` can handle it.

Comment: You can also setup a key for `git`, so `go` will be able to fetch all required deps, so no need to do this manually.

Comment: check the permission for  `ls-la ~/.ssh/id_rsa`, if you have the write permission then remove it by running `chmod 600 id_rsa`

Comment: Thanks. I supplied my public key at github.com. Now other libraries like `github.com/disintegration/imaging` install without problems. But still when I execute `go get -u -v github.com/KangSpace/gqrcode` I get an error: 
`github.com/KangSpace/gqrcode (download)
github.com/gqrcode/core (download)
# cd .; git clone -- https://github.com/gqrcode/core /home/user/go/src/github.com/gqrcode/core
Cloning into '/home/user/go/src/github.com/gqrcode/core'...
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`
Is the github maintainer doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it stills uses an HTTPS URL, despite your global git config `url."git@github.com:".insteadOf` directive, you might need and try using a [PAT (personal access token)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) instead.

As in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71006305/6309), try

```
git config --global url."https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}:x-oauth-basic@github.com/".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```

(Assuming you have access to the repository)

Howver, considering https://github.com/gqrcode itself is 404, the `github.com/gqrcode/xxx` imports declared in [github.com/KangSpace/gqrcode](https://github.com/KangSpace/gqrcode/search?q=gqrcode) might need to be updated first.