# Git ssh protocol for remote repository gives Permission denied (publickey) message

Tags: macos, git, ubuntu, github, ssh

I try to create remote repository  in my own Ubuntu server(SFTP). I installed and config Git by follow this link : http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server. Then try to push my code to server from my local machine it gives following error.

```
$ git push origin master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights 
and the repository exists."
```

The public keys are available in local `.ssh` directory as well as in server `authorized_keys` file.
How would you troubleshoot this?

Comment: Are you sure the path of the repo is correct? (`git@gitserver:/path/to/your/project.git`), with the right case?

Comment: i am using my own server that will like (servername@ip:/home/git/project.git)

Comment: I understand: same question than before, but adapted to your server, obviously: Are you sure the path of the repo is correct? (`/home/git/project.git`)

Comment: yes thats correct i created project.git with in git directory and initialize it.

Comment: Ok. Just to understand, why are you mentioning sftp, while the link you mention is about ssh and running the sshd (ssh daemon) to listen to git queries over ssh?

Comment: My server type is SFTP is it any problem to access remote repository?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with sftp. I only use sshd.

Comment: okay i need sshd only. how can i solve this above error.

Comment: A few ssh debugging tips: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17774456/6309 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/11758664/6309